# Evaluate $\displaystyle\int_{[0,\infty)} e^{-\lambda u}\, \text{d}F$

Tags: lebesgue-integral, cumulative-distribution-functions

Given the following [half-maximum convention of the Heaviside](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function#Discrete_form) function at $1$,
$$
F(u) = \begin{cases}
\ 1 & \text{if \(u>1\)} \\
\ 1/2 & \text{if \(u=1\)} \\
\ 0 & \text{if \(u<1\)} \\
\end{cases}
$$
evaluate the Lebesgue integral:
$$
\int_{[0,\infty)} e^{-\lambda u}\, \text{d}F.
$$

I somehow get the thought on the usual Heaviside function without the $\frac{1}{2}$ but
I just can't wrap-up the idea on how to proceed for the half-maximum version. Any thoughts?

Comment: $F$ is not a cumulative distribution function since it is not right-continuous at $1$. There is no measure corresponding to it and the integral cannot be defined in Lebesgue sense.

Comment: @geetha290krm it seems reasonable to me that $dF$ would be two stacked point masses (effectively one point mass). Why is that not allowed?

Comment: @NinadMunshi $\mu (-\infty,x)$ is left continuous and $\mu (-\infty,x]$ is right continuous. Since $F$ is neither left continuous nor right continuous the usual definitions do not cover this.

Comment: Again, I don't see why that's relevant. The arbitrary actions of redefining points all occur on a set of measure zero, which we know logically should not affect anything in a measure theory sense. It seems to me you are confusing the theory of measures in general with the theory of probability measures in specific. Maybe it's the way OP phrased their question? I generally don't interpret (and neither do many people) Lebesgue integration as integration specifically w.r.t. a Lebesgue measure.

Comment: I apologize for the confusion. I made a mistake of writing that should strictly be a Lebesgue measure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\mathrm d F = 0$ (say in the sense of distributions) on $[2,\infty)$, it is sufficient to look at the integral on $[0,2]$. Let $f(x) = e^{-\lambda x}$. By definition of the Stieltjes integral, one has to compute
$$
S_X = \sum_{k=1}^n f(c_k)\left(F(x_{k+1})-F(x_k)\right)
$$
for every $n\in\Bbb N$ and every partition $X=(x_k)_{k=1...n}$ with $x_1 = 0$ and $x_n = 2$, and with $c_k\in[x_k,x_{k+1}]$ and make the size of the longest subinterval $\delta_X = \sup_{0\leq k<n} |x_{k+1}-x_k|\to 0$.

- If $x_k$ is never $1$, then there is $k_0$ such that $x_{k_0}<1<x_{k_0+1}$, and so
  $$
  S_X = f(c_{k_0})
  $$
  with $x_{k_0}<1<x_{k_0+1}$ and so $|c_{k_0}-1|\leq \delta_X$.
- If there is $k_0$ such that $x_{k_0} = 1$, then
  $$
  S_X = \frac{1}{2}\left(f(c_{k_0})+f(c_{k_0-1})\right)
  $$
  with $x_{k_0-1}\leq c_{k_0-1}\leq 1 \leq c_{k_0}\leq x_{k_0+1}$ and so $|c_{k_0}-1|\leq \delta_X$ and $|c_{k_0-1}-1|\leq \delta_X$.

In all the cases, when $\delta_X\to 0$, $c_{k_0}\to 1$ and $c_{k_0-1}\to 1$, and so since $f$ is continuous, one deduces that $S_X\to f(1)$. Hence
$$
\int_0^\infty e^{-\lambda \,x}\,\mathrm d F(x) = e^{-\lambda}.
$$
So the $1/2$ does not change anything, one still gets $\mathrm d F = \delta_1$.